# Проблема с ViewPager ом в NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

Моя лейаут структура:

```
<RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout>...</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout>...</RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Мне нужен один не скролящийся RelativeLayout и под ним скролящиеся [RelativeLayout, TabLayout and ViewPager].

Но изза [этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580954/viewpager-in-a-nestedscrollview) проблемы ViewPager исчезает из лейаута когда он находиться в NestedScrollView. Решение с

```
setFillViewport (true)
```

не решает моей проблемы потому что NestedScrollView начинает fitting view port (очевидно=)) и обрезает не влезшую в экран часть ViewPager.

Итак **вопрос**: Какой правильный путь для создания скролящегося лейаутакоторый содержит лейауты + view pager

Comment: А если вместо нестед использовать обычный `ScrollView`?

Comment: @eugeneek, пробовал ничего не поменялось

Comment: Тогда вариант всё скролящееся класть в `RecyclerVIew`, с разными типами ячеек.

Comment: @eugeneek да такой вариант подошел, похоже что это самое лучшее решение!